# powershell manage multiple windows service on multiple remote servers

Tags: windows, powershell, service, remote-server

I want to start/stop set of windows service on each of more than one remote servers. I've created one powershell in which i am passing values in a csv file for server name and service. but i want this should be in below manner:-

One text file shd contain list of remote server

One text file shd contain list of services.

One powershell script which will either start or stop all the services mentioned in second text file on first server listed in first text file, once done with first server it shd go to second server with all these services and so on till last entry in list of remote server.

Comment: Is there some dependency involved - i.e. do all of the services need to be in a Started or Stopped state before moving on to the next server?  Do you need to handle exceptions and errors, if e.g. a service fails to start, or gets hung in a Starting or Stopping state?

Comment: OK. So what have you attempted in the course of solving this? At what point are you getting stuck. Show your work - don't ask people here to do it all for you.

Comment: Hi mjolinor and alroc,

I've written a powershell script as below:

Import-Csv ServerAndServiceName.csv | Get-service | start-service

 and in csv file i am passing below as computer name and service name:

ComputerName,Name

Server1,Service1

My concern is If i need to manage multiple services on multiple servers then i need to write a separate line of code for each service on single server then again same for next server.

I just want avoid lengthy csv file with simple two text files which i've mentioned in my question.

Any suggestion welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I have found solution to above.

I've created two separate text files, one for server name say `servers.txt` and one is for service name say `services.txt`

In my PowerShell script I've written below and worked fine for me:

```
$serverList  = gc servers.txt
$serviceList = gc services.txt

ForEach ($server in $serverList)
{
    ForEach ($service in $serviceList)
    {
        Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $server | Start-service
    }
}
```

Thanks again to all who have responded here on my question.

Comment: This is *not* a good solution, since the only association between host name and services is the line number in the two separate files.

Comment: Could this happen in a parral way?

Answer (score 0):

You could put the service names as a comma-separated list in a tab-separated file:

```
Hostname    Services
HostA   ServiceA,ServiceB
HostB   ServiceA,ServiceC,ServiceD
HostC   ServiceB,ServiceC
```

and process the file like this:

```
Import-Csv C:\path\to\list.tsv -Delimiter "`t" | % {
  $services = $_.Services -split ','
  Start-Service -Computer $_.Hostname -Name $services
}
```